# Laravel 5.2 - Mollie API - webhook not working

Tags: php, laravel, webhooks, mollie

I'm trying to do do sometype of "Premium" system on my webapp, however I'm having troubles with handling the payment.

I'm using the [Mollie Api](https://www.mollie.com/en/docs/webhook) and I found [THIS](https://github.com/petericebear/laravel-mollie) on github that integrates it into laravel.

```
public function postMedium()
{
    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $payment = Mollie::getPayments()->create([
        "amount"      => 9.99,
        "description" => "Foodtruck Bestellen Premium - 1 Month",
        "webhookUrl"  => "URL",
        "redirectUrl" => "URL",
        "metadata"    => array(
            'user_id' => $user_id
        )
    ]);
    return redirect($payment->links->paymentUrl);
}


public function mediumPaymentCheck(Request $request)
{
    $payment = Mollie::getPayments()->get(Input::get('id'));
    if ($payment->isPaid()) {

        $user_id = $payment->user_id;

        $user = User::find($user_id);

        $user->premium = true;
        $user->premium_type = "medium";
        $user->premium_expiry_date = Carbon::now()->addDays(30);

        $user->save();
    }
}
```

After the payment you get redirected to the redirectUrl and that works.

However...

Nothing changes in my DB, so it seems like my webhook url ("mediumPaymentCheck") is being ignored or not working for some reason.

I hope someone can help me out!

**Edit: my webhook url looks like this:**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
Route::post('/premium/payment/medium/check', 'PremiumController@mediumPaymentCheck');
```

Comment: I would first make sure API hits my callback url. So put `\Log::info('Received');` or something like that in `mediumPaymentCheck` method, to be sure, that API is coming to Your callback url. Also I hope You just masked Your real urls with `URL` thing.

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys It doesn't log anything. How is this possible? I editted the OP with my routes. And yes, URL thing is just a mask for stack! :)

Comment: Do You added csrf exception to that url? Because API will return data in POST method, so by default in web middleware, csrf check will be fired.

Comment: Is your webhook URL reachable from the internet?

Comment: @GiedriusKiršys Removing the CSRF middleware from the url fixed it, thanks buddy!